# Radio Button Click event for 3 row which finally check Final RadioButtom

Tags: android, radio-group

What i want to do is 
I have 3 Radio Button on the Head
saying Yes, No, NA

Followed By 2 Radio Button in 3 Roows

What i want is if All the YES are Checked in 3 Rows 
Header YES is Checked

If NO is Checked in Either of 3 Rows Then 
Header No is Checked

How Can i DO that

I have made 3 Radio Group  for this

Please have a refernce throu a pic
[image]

What i have tried is

for Header row

```
                vctOptionPoint=new Vector<String>();
                vctAnswerID=new Vector<String>();
                int iOpCount=3;
                RadioGroup rg=new RadioGroup(this);
                rg.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                rg.setId(idRadioGroup);
                rg.setOrientation(android.widget.RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);
                rg.setPadding(5, 0, 0, 0);
                for(int j=0;j<iOpCount;j++){
                    String sOption="";
                    if(j==0){
                        sOption="Yes";
                        vctOptionPoint.addElement(sQuestionPoints);
                    }
                    else if(j==1){
                        sOption="No";
                        vctOptionPoint.addElement("0");
                    }
                    if(j==2){
                        sOption="NA";
                        vctOptionPoint.addElement("0");
                    }
                    vctAnswerID.addElement(String.valueOf(j));

                    RadioButton rb=new RadioButton(this);
                    rb.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    rb.setText(sOption);
                    if(sAnswerText.toString().equals(sOption)){
                        rb.setChecked(true);
                    }
                    rb.setId(idRadioButton);
                    idRadioButton++;                            
                    rg.addView(rb);
                }
                rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(rb_onCheckedChange);
                ll.addView(rg);
```

For 2nd Row

```
vctOptionPoint2=new Vector<String>();
            vctAnswerID2=new Vector<String>();
            int iOpCount=2;
            RadioGroup rg1=new RadioGroup(this);
            rg1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            rg1.setId(idRadioGroup);
            rg1.setOrientation(android.widget.RadioGroup.HORIZONTAL);
            rg1.setPadding(5, 0, 0, 0);
            for(int j=0;j<iOpCount;j++){
                String sOption="";
                if(j==0){
                    sOption="Yes";
                    vctOptionPoint2.addElement(sQuestionPoints);
                }
                else if(j==1){
                    sOption="No";
                    vctOptionPoint2.addElement("0");
                }
                vctAnswerID2.addElement(String.valueOf(j));

                RadioButton rb1=new RadioButton(this);
                rb1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                rb1.setText(sOption);
                rb1.setChecked(false);
                if(sAnswerText.toString().equals(sOption)){
                    //rb1.setChecked(true);
                }
                rb1.setId(idRadioButton2);
                idRadioButton2++;                           
                rg1.addView(rb1);
            }
            rg1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(rb_onCheckedChange_New);
```

Same Fore 3rd and 4th Row

Checked Changed Method

```
OnCheckedChangeListener rb_onCheckedChange_New=new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup rg,int arg1){
            idRadioButton=4;
            idRadioButton2=15;
            idRadioButton1=13;
            idRadioButton11=14;


            int iRGChildCount=rg.getChildCount();
            for(int yy=0;yy<iRGChildCount;yy++){
                RadioButton rb=(RadioButton)rg.findViewById(idRadioButton);
                RadioButton rb1=(RadioButton)rg.findViewById(idRadioButton2);
                RadioButton rb2=(RadioButton)rg.findViewById(idRadioButton1);
                RadioButton rb3=(RadioButton)rg.findViewById(idRadioButton11);

                if((rb1!=null)){
                    if(rb1.isChecked() && rb2.isChecked() && rb3.isChecked()){
                        //int iQusPoints=Integer.parseInt((String)vctOptionPoint2.elementAt(idRadioButton-4));
                        String sOption1=rb1.getText().toString();
                        String sOption2=rb2.getText().toString();
                        String sOption3=rb3.getText().toString();

                        if(sOption1.equals("No") || sOption2.equals("No") || sOption3.equals("No") ){
                            tvSecCount1.setText("Points : 0\nScored : 0");
                        }
                        else if(sOption1.equals("Yes") || sOption2.equals("No") || sOption3.equals("No") ){
                            int iQusPoints=0;
                            tvSecCount1.setText("Points : "+sQuestionPoints+"\nScored : "+iQusPoints);

                        }
                        else if(sOption1.equals("No") || sOption2.equals("Yes") || sOption3.equals("No") ){
                            int iQusPoints=0;
                            tvSecCount1.setText("Points : "+sQuestionPoints+"\nScored : "+iQusPoints);

                        }
                        else if(sOption1.equals("No") || sOption2.equals("No") || sOption3.equals("Yes") ){
                            int iQusPoints=0;
                            tvSecCount1.setText("Points : "+sQuestionPoints+"\nScored : "+iQusPoints);

                        }
                        else if(sOption1.equals("Yes") || sOption2.equals("Yes") || sOption3.equals("No") ){
                            int iQusPoints=0;
                            tvSecCount1.setText("Points : "+sQuestionPoints+"\nScored : "+iQusPoints);

                        }
                        else if(sOption1.equals("No") || sOption2.equals("Yes") || sOption3.equals("Yes") ){
                            int iQusPoints=0;
                            tvSecCount1.setText("Points : "+sQuestionPoints+"\nScored : "+iQusPoints);
                        }
                        else{
                            int iQusPoints=2;
                            tvSecCount1.setText("Points : "+sQuestionPoints+"\nScored : "+iQusPoints);
                            if(sOption1.equals("Yes") && sOption2.equals("Yes") && sOption3.equals("Yes") ){
                                //fnNext();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                idRadioButton++;
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: How far did you get your code working. And why you have used a vector any need for `synchronization`

Comment: Oh man, why did you complicate it so much? You could do the same much shorter and easier to follow the code... And why do you set radio button IDs directly instead of using static reference names of R class?

Comment: Give me a moment and I will post a much better solution, if you don't mind...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

res/values/strings.xml (Please always make use of strings.xml file)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="yes">Yes</string>
    <string name="no">No</string>
    <string name="na">NA</string>
</resources>
```

res/layout/activity_main.xml (Change layout any way you want, I made it really simple just for testing purposes)

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioHeader"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioHeaderYes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="@string/yes" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioHeaderNo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/no" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioHeaderNA"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/na" />
</RadioGroup>

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1Yes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="@string/yes" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1No"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/no" />
</RadioGroup>

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio2Yes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="@string/yes" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio2No"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/no" />
</RadioGroup>

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio3Yes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="@string/yes" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio3No"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/no" />
</RadioGroup>
```

MainActivity.java (See how much Java code I need for this...)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Boolean[] radioGroups;
RadioGroup radioHeader, radioGroup1, radioGroup2, radioGroup3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    radioGroups = new Boolean[] {true, true, true};
    initViews();
}

private void initViews() {
    radioHeader = (RadioGroup) this.findViewById(R.id.radioHeader);
    radioGroup1 = (RadioGroup) this.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    radioGroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            radioGroups[0] = checkedId == R.id.radio1Yes;
            refreshHeader();
        }
    });
    radioGroup2 = (RadioGroup) this.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup2);
    radioGroup2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            radioGroups[1] = checkedId == R.id.radio2Yes;
            refreshHeader();
        }
    });
    radioGroup3 = (RadioGroup) this.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup3);
    radioGroup3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            radioGroups[2] = checkedId == R.id.radio3Yes;
            refreshHeader();
        }
    });
}

private void refreshHeader() {
    radioHeader.check(radioGroups[0] & radioGroups[1] & radioGroups[2] ? R.id.radioHeaderYes : R.id.radioHeaderNo);
}
```

Comment: Well Thanks for it But i would to do it dynamically Thanks for your help !!

Comment: You're welcome. You could just replace the XML layout design for Java code at the beginning of the `initViews` method, and that's all. Anyway... you got the idea!